How to avoid deprecation warnings in Data.DB module
In Delphi 10.3 Rio, when I add any modules inherited from TDataSet into my project , it causes a bunch of warnings during compilation, like:

[dcc32 Warning] Data.DB.pas(2508): W1000 Symbol 'IProviderSupport' is deprecated: 'Use IProviderSupportNG instead'

What should I do to avoid these messages? I don't want to suppress all deprecation messages, edit the source code of Data.DB library, or remove the source code of it at all.
Is there another way to remove these warnings?

Why do you compile Data.DB.pas at all? If you want to step through its source during debugging you should enable "With debug DCUs" in the project options and remove the path to Data.DB.pas from the library path.

I didn't know about it. Thank you.
